# Delphi 10.4.1, Service in Android App with Timer

Tags: android, delphi, service, timer, delphi-10.4-sydney

I found that with Delphi 10.4.1, putting a Timer component on the datamodule of a service associated with a multi-device app, starting the service the app closes immediately.

I assume it's a bug that has since been fixed in later versions.

I need to keep a cycle running within the service that periodically updates (every 2-3 hours) the data inside with data coming from an external server.

Not being able with timer, therefore in my case, to use timers, I had thought of a thread with a while loop inside it which verifies the timestamp and carries out the queries needed every certain period of time.

But I don't know if this would consume too many resources on the phone.

Would you have any suggestions?

Comment: The issue of using TTimer in an Android service has been [reported here](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17857). Doing what you desire is becoming harder to manage with each new version of Android. For your scenario, it is recommended that you use a Worker class, however this is [yet to be implemented in Delphi](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-36884). An alternative is to implement a Worker in Java code, and integrate it to your project. I'm unaware of any examples of doing this in Delphi. I was going to attempt this myself but have had other priorities

Answer (score 0):

Try using a native Android timer, not the Delphi TTimer. There is a source code coming with DelphiWorlds KastiFree that I use successful standalone without the rest of this package.
Find the unit here:
[AndroidTimer](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/blob/master/Demos/AndroidLocation/Common/LS.AndroidTimer.pas)

Answer (score 0):

create a thread that runs in the background and progresses every 1 second (or the desired number of seconds), and execute the procedure after sleep.

In the form's private declare the variable:

```
MyThread: TThread;
```

Create a procedure that starts the thread:

```
procedure TFrmPrincipal.StartThread;
begin
   MyThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
   procedure
   begin
     while not MyThread.CheckTerminated do
     begin
       // progressing every 1 second (or the desired number of seconds)
       Sleep(1000);

       // here execute commands that do not interact with the screen
       // ....

       TThread.Synchronize(TThread.currentthread,
       procedure
       begin
         // here execute commands that do interact with the screen
         // ....
       end);
     end;
   end);

   MyThread.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminate;
   MyThread.FreeOnTerminate := False;
   MyThread.Start;
end;
```

Write an onTerminate for the Thread, so you catch any errors:

```
procedure TFrmPrincipal.ThreadTerminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if Sender is TThread then
   begin
     if Assigned(TThread(Sender).FatalException) then
     begin
       showmessage(Exception(TThread(Sender).FatalException).Message);
       Exit;
     end;
   end;
end;
```

In the form close write to avoid memoryleak:

```
if Assigned(MyThread) then
   begin
     MyThread.Terminate;
     FreeAndNil(MyThread);
   end;
```

In the form show start MyThread:

```
StartThread;
```